# Protocol buffer SerializeToArray: How to find which structure has been serialized

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using ProtoBuf to communicate between client and server using structures. I call `SerializeToArray` and then send the obtained buffer across wire and to the other end I call same structure's `ParseFromArray` method to get back the values in structure. And it works as expected.

However, if there are multiple structures involved and if I have to send any of them to the other end. I am not sure how at the other end shall I find out which structure has been serialized? (So I can call its `ParseFromArray` to get values)

One way I can think of to go around this problem is to keep first bye of all structure as "ID Byte". So when any structure gets serialized in buffer, I can always read first byte of buffer to find which structure it was.

But I am not sure if this is standard way of doing it and and if it will work on all platforms.

Please can someone throw light?

**Update:**

Thanks to  Kenton Varda for the tip. I've decided to use [`Oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof) feature to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is use [Protobuf's `oneof` declaration](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof) to define an outer wrapper type, like:

```
message MyMessage {
  oneof value {
    Foo foo = 1;
    Bar bar = 2;
    Baz baz = 3;
  }
}
```

The protobuf system will make sure that only one of `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` is filled in and let you write a `switch` over these.

Note that this feature is new in version 2.6 and third-party Protobuf implementations may not yet be updated to support it. However, in these third-party implementations, the declaration should behave like a set of `optional` fields, which is still usable; it's just that you'll need a series of `if`/`else` statements that checks `has_foo()`, `has_bar()`, etc.

Comment: Alternatively we can also write `switch (mymessage.value_case())` which will have cases `MyMessage::kfoo`, `MyMessage::kbar` and `MyMessage::kbaz` These are enumerations Protobuf provides.

Comment: @Atul Right, that works in implementations that support `oneof`. What I was saying is that some older or third-party protobuf implementations do not yet support `oneof`, and with those you'll have to use `has_*()`.

Answer (score 0):

As ProtoBuf messages are not self-descriptive you'll need to specify the kind of message you are serializing.

You can either:

1. Have the first byte denoting the message
2. Setup your protocol in such a way that the order of messages are known (e.g. A request is received, a reply must be sent)

Comment: So, first byte of structure would _always_ be first byte of buffer? That's the whole point of my question.

Comment: @Atul I was thinking something like [1b: message type][4b:message length][nb: the actual array]. Prefixing a message with it's type and the length. Maybe 4 bytes is an overkill in your situation

Comment: @Atul Option (2) is better. Use [Protobuf's `oneof` declaration](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof) to define an outer "envelope" type which can contain exactly one of the different possible types.

Comment: @KentonVarda This is simply great tip. `oneof` is something what I was really looking for. You may write this as an answer.

Comment: @Atul done! (Also I'm not sure why I said "Option (2) is better"; re-reading option (2) now it doesn't look anything like what I was thinking. Maybe I had misread.)